# Page displays on everything except Internet Explorer 11

Tags: jquery, search, browser

We have a page of speakers' files (mp3s) that our members can play.

It works in everything except IE11.
It works with IE10.
It validates with NO errors or warnings with validator.w3.org

Does anyone have any idea of why? It flashes the files, then they disappear. I'm using a JQuery search functions that hides/shows if something is entered in the search box. You can see 30 pages in the paginator and if you enter a letter in the search, that number drops to 1 or 2. This means everything works... well, except for showing the speakers.

---

Here's the page: http://oalaig.org/podcasttest/index.php

Here is a shortened version (only two rows) of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Los Angeles Intergroup Speakers</title>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10">
      <META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex, nofollow">
      <META NAME="GOOGLEBOT" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
      <link rel="icon" href="favicon.gif" type="image/x-icon" />
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.gif" type="image/x-icon" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">   
      <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery/jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="wimpy/wimpy.js"></script>   
      <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery/__jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="clipboard.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="JQuery/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

      <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn');

            $("#maintable").tablesorter({

            headers: {
                0: {
                    sorter: false
                },              
                4: { 
                    dateFormat: "mmddyyyy" 
                },
                8: {
                    sorter: false
                },              
                9: {
                    sorter: false
                }               
            }   
            });             

            $("#maintable").tablesorterPager({
                container: $("#pager"), 
                size: 30
            });             

            var lnCntr = 0;

            $("#search").keyup(function() {
                var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
                lnCntr = 0;

                if (value == "") {
                    $("#maintable").tablesorterPager({
                        container: $("#pager"), 
                        size: 30
                    });             
                } else {
                    $("#maintable").tablesorterPager({
                        container: $("#pager"), 
                        size: 3000
                    });             
                }

                $("table").find("tr").each(function(index) {
                    if (index === 0) {
                        return;
                    }

                    var id = $(this).find("td").eq(1).text();
                    var what = value;
                    if (id.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1) {
                      $(this).show();
                    } else {
                      $(this).hide();
                      lnCntr = lnCntr + 1;
                    }
                });
                if (lnCntr === 0) {
                    $("#maintable").tablesorterPager({
                        container: $("#pager"), 
                        size: 30
                    });             
                }
            });
        });  

    $('.playbutton').live('click', function(){
      var thisvar     = $(this);
      var newnumber = thisvar[0].id;
      var newnumber2 = thisvar[0].id;
      var thisValue = thisvar[0].value;
      $("#" + newnumber).html('Close');
      newnumber = newnumber.replace('button','');
      whatID="myPlayer" + newnumber;
      if (thisValue == 1) {
          thisvar[0].value = 0;
          $("#" + newnumber2).html("<img src='playbutton-final.png' alt='Play Button'/>");

          $(this).closest('tr').next().remove();
          return;
      }
      thisvar[0].value = 1;

      var lcPlayName  = document.getElementById("playname" + newnumber).value;   
      var PlayJSON = JSON.parse(lcPlayName);                    
      PlayJSON.album = "The LAIG Virtual Speakers Bureau";
      var PlayDate = PlayJSON.artist;
      var DateMeet = PlayDate.split("|");
      var lcString = "";
      switch (DateMeet[1]) {
          case "K":
            lcString = "the Kitchen Sink meeting in Beverly Hills";
            break;

          case "L":
            lcString = "the Kitchen Sink meeting in Los Angeles";
            break;

          default:
            lcString = "A meeting in Los Angeles";
            break;

      }
      var lcStringFull = "Recorded at " + lcString + ", CA on " + DateMeet[0];
      PlayJSON.artist = lcStringFull;
      lcPlayName2 = JSON.stringify(PlayJSON);

      $parentTR = thisvar.closest('tr');
      var newrow = "<tr id='playerrow" + newnumber + "' class='row-details expand-child'>\n";
      newrow = newrow + "<td colspan='10'><div id='myPlayerDiv" + newnumber + "' class='wimpy'></div>\n";
      newrow = newrow + "</td>\n";
      newrow = newrow + "</tr>\n";

        if ($(window).width() < 960) {
          lcSkin = "001.tsv";
        }
        else {
          lcSkin = "003.tsv";
        }  

      var divNumber = "myPlayerDiv" + newnumber;
      $($parentTR).after(newrow);
      var myPlayer = new wimpyPlayer({
                                target: divNumber,           
                                media: lcPlayName2,
                                autoPlay: 1,
                                infoFormat: '1 - 2 - 3 ',
                                infoscroll: 1,
                                responsive: 1,
                                skin: lcSkin 
                              });
    });
    </script>     
  </head>

  <body onload="">
        <div class="master-wrapper">
    <div class="pageCenter">
      <div id="uppertable">
        <div id="searchandtitle">

      <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search Speakers" size="30" />
      <H5>Click on column headers to sort by that field.</H5>
        </div>

        <div id="pager" class="pager">
            <form>30 podcasts per page, for additional pages look here &rarr;
                <img src="addons/pager/icons/first.png" class="first" alt='First'/>
                <img src="addons/pager/icons/prev.png" class="prev" alt='Previous'/>
                <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
                <img src="addons/pager/icons/next.png" class="next" alt='Next'/>
                <img src="addons/pager/icons/last.png" class="last" alt='Last'/>
                <select class="pagesize">
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="40">40</option>
                    <option value="4000">All</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <table id="maintable" class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <th>Play</th>
          <th>Speaker</th>
          <th><div class="tooltip2">Key&nbsp;<img src="qm.png" height="12" alt="Question Mark"/><span class="tooltiptext">Keys<br />A: Anorexic/Bulimic <br />O:Overeater <br />#: 100 pounder <br />G: Gay/Lesbian <br />+: Multiple Addictions <br />C: Person of color</span></div></th>
          <th>In OA<br />Since</th>
          <th>Date<br />Recorded</th>
          <th>Meeting Name<br />and Location</th>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>File Size</th>
          <th><div class="tooltip">Download&nbsp;<img src="qm.png" height="12" alt="Question Mark"/><span class="tooltiptext">If your browser won't download, right click the link and 'Save As'</span></div></th>
          <th><div class="tooltip">Copy Link&nbsp;<img src="qm.png" height="12" alt="Question Mark"/><span class="tooltiptext">Copy link information to share with others</span></div></th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>


<tr id='row1'>
<td><button id='button1' class='playbutton' value='0'><img id='playimage1' src='playbutton-final.png' alt='Play Button'/></button></td>
<td>Michelle R.</td>
<td>O</td>
<td>2011<td>07/08/2017</td>
<td>Light a Candle meeting<br />Brentwood, CA</td>
<td>38:22</td>
<td>8.79 MB</td>
<td class='downloadcell'><a href='2017-07-08_michelle_r_lac.mp3' class='button2' download>Download</a></td>
<td><button class='btn' data-clipboard-target='#filename1'>Copy</button></td>
</tr>
<tr class='oddrow' id='row2'>
<td><button id='button2' class='playbutton' value='0'><img id='playimage2' src='playbutton-final.png' alt='Play Button'/></button></td>
<td>Lyseanne N.</td>
<td>O,+,A</td>
<td>2002<td>07/01/2017</td>
<td>Light a Candle meeting<br />Brentwood, CA</td>
<td>32:26</td>
<td>3.72 MB</td>
<td class='downloadcell'><a href='2017-07-01_lyseanne_n_lac.mp3' class='button2' download>Download</a></td>
<td><button class='btn' data-clipboard-target='#filename2'>Copy</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type='text' class='hideit' id='filecount' value='827'>
<input type='text' class='hideit' id='filename1' value='2017-07-08_michelle_r_lac.mp3'>
<input type='text' class='hideit' id='filename2' value='2017-07-01_lyseanne_n_lac.mp3'>
<input type='text' class='hideit' id='playname2' value='{"file":"2017-07-01_lyseanne_n_lac.mp3", "title":"Lyseanne N.", "artist":"07/01/2017|K", "album":"@"}'>
<input type='text' class='hideit' id='playname3' value='{"file":"2017-06-29_podcast_update__oth.mp3", "title":"Podcast Update", "artist":"06/29/2017|K", "album":"@"}'>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://www.oalaig.org/wpoa/wp-content/themes/laig/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce. The audio plays fine for me in IE 11 / win 10[image]

Comment: Crap.  So weird.  It also works on other websites, but on my setup, it doesn't work on the live site.  Can someone try it with IE11 who is running Windows 7?  Thanks to whomever does this.  PS:  Thanks Tony!

Comment: Microsoft has some virtual machines you can download 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

Comment: Also try to start IE without any extensions. From a command prompt 
cd "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" and run 
iexplore.exe -extoff